# Convergence of a subsequence of Bernoulli random variables

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables

Let $(B_n)_n$ be a sequence of independent Bernoulli random variables with $P(B_n=1)=1/n, n \in \Bbb N$. How to show that there exists a subsequence $(B_ {n_k} )$ s.t. $\lim_{k \to \infty} B_{n_k}=0$? Is it possible to find a deterministic subsequence? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried any deterministic subsequences? Since you have independence, they are straightforward to reason about.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen, We may even drop the independence here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can show that $B_n$ converges to 0 in probability, and then apply the standard result that convergence in probability implies the existence of a subsequence converging a.s.

Comment: You can certainly do that, but there is a simple from-scratch way here where also the indices are deterministic.